# Java sockets not connecting

Tags: java, sockets

I'm creating a simple messaging app, and everything works when using the localhost and my internal IP address, but when I send a client to my brother for him to run, they never connect. I've port forwarded the correct port on my router, and forwarded it to my computer running the server. The IP I'm having his client try to connect to was gotten by typing "whats my ip" into Google, and using that.

Here's the relevant code from the server.

```
ServerSocket start = new ServerSocket(50123);
Socket live = start.accept();
start.close();
```

And here's the code for the client, where ########## is the IP from the Google search.

```
Socket live = new Socket("##########", 50123);
InputStream input = live.getInputStream();
OutputStream output = live.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: Test the port forwarding with something other than your software to make sure it's correct (it's probably not).

Comment: I just checked it with an online tool, and it does indeed say it's closed, but I'm not sure why. When I go into my router's dashboard it shows under the Virtual Servers section that my computer is set as the target for the port. My internal IP is also static, so I'm not sure what could be the issue.